# Why are the options to validate or upload to appStore grayed in Xcode 8?

Tags: xcode8

I am trying to upload my first app to Appstore, but after I archieve it, the options to upload and validate are grayed. Please advise

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: In the first two screenshots the Code Signing Identity build setting is set to Don't Code Sign. If you choose a code signing identity for the Release build configuration and archive the app, is the Upload to App Store button enabled in the Organizer?

Comment: @MarkSzymczyk   To answer your question, the button was disabled. I later found that the bundle ID that was displayed under Targets/General/Bundle Identifier was not the same with the string when I did show pakage contents on the Xcode project. After I corrected the bundle ID I checked the  box Automatically manage signing and it worked.